# jQuery UI datepicker setDate with new Date vs Date.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

What is the difference between

```
  new Date(2013,0,1)
```

and

```
  Date.parse("2013-1-1")
```

that breaks http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tawVx/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, not a `Date` object.

[setDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) takes either a `Date` object or a string, not a number of milliseconds elapsed since the epoch.

The following code would work:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date(Date.parse("2013-01-01")));
```